# passing username and password with special symbols in the URL

Tags: jquery

When I am using **encodeURIComponent** then I am getting incorrect password and when I am using # or any other symbol in password I am not able to login. For passwords without symbol I can easily login. Any solution so that I am able to use special characters in the url without breaking the normal flow of my code.

```js
$("#btnLogin").click(function () {
    ValidateLoginForm() && ($("#btnLogin").addClass("myprogress"), $.post("http://tester.icaresoftware.com/Service%20References/LoginService.asmx/Login", {
        UserEmail: $("#userEmailAddress").val(),
        Password: $("#userPassword").val()
    }, function (e) {
        debugger;
        var uri = encodeURIComponent("http://tester.icaresoftware.com/Gateway/Gateway/RedirectFromWeb?UserEmail=" + $("#userEmailAddress").val() + "&Password=" + $("#userPassword").val() );
        $("#btnLogin").removeClass("myprogress"), "Success" == $($(e)[0]).text() ? location.href = uri: $(".msg-area").html("<span>The email address or password you entered is incorrect.</span>")
    }))
```

Comment: You should never ever pass a password as part of the url in a GET request (e.g. 
 setting `location.href`). This will store the password in the history of the browser.

Comment: `$.post` should already do the correct escaping, so if `$.post` does not work then the problem is server side. If it is about the  `location.href = uri`, then you should find another solution anyway. And `encodeURIComponent` should not be applied on the complete url, but only on the part that needs escaping.

Comment: In case we are following above case then whats the solution to pass passwords with special characters and if possible provide any alternative code for above case.

Comment: I don't understand the need of sending password with `GET` request at the first place.

Comment: you can try `encodeURIComponent` to encode special characters in username/password. But this is a very, very bad idea to have the password in URL. Even HTTPS can't save you as the password is there in URL. You should post it to the server and preferably over HTTPS.